# Anti-pattern or acceptable way of using Promises?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise

Whenever I need to use a Promise interface in my NodeJs code and I don't have a promise to start off with, I do this:

```
var someResultPromise = Q.resolve()
    .then(function () {
        var something = 'value';

        var anotherPromise = callFunctionThatReturnsPromise(something)
            .then(function (result) {
                return processing(result);
            });

        return anotherPromise;
    });
```

Is this a good way to do it? If no, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Q.resolve()` and the outer `then(function() {...})` are not necessary. Your code will simplify to ...

```
var something = 'value';
var someResultPromise = callFunctionThatReturnsPromise(something).then(function (result) {
    return processing(result);
});
```

... and in general that is what we would write.

However sometimes it's advantageous to start a promise chain with a resolved promise, even if it's not strictly necessary.

For example, we might want a chain such as ...

```
var promise = doSomethingAsync()
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync);
```

... but we might choose to write ...

```
var promise = Q.resolve()
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync);
```

... which is functionally identical but easier on the eye because it allows the first `doSomethingAsync` to be coded the same as all the others; it does not appear to be a special case.

Answer (score 1):

`then` can act differently depending on what you return from it:

- If it returns nothing, the next chained `then` will resolve with <s>the original resolved value</s> `undefined`.

  ```
  doSomethingAsync().then(function(data){
    // do nothing
  }).then(function(data2){
    // `data2` will be `undefined`
  });
  ```
- If it returns a non-promise value, the next chained `then` will resolve with the returned value.

  ```
  doSomethingAsync().then(function(data){
    return 3;
  }).then(function(three){
    three === 3; // true
  });
  ```
- If it returns a promise object, the next chained `then` will resolve with the value resolved from that promise

  ```
  doSomethingAsync().then(function(data){
    return $.get('http://google.com', { q: data });
  }).then(function(dataFromGoogle){
    // This will only resolve when $.get resolves and with the
    // resolved value from $.get instead of doSomethingAsync
  });
  ```

Promises were designed to allow you to "return" the value of an async operation into the next chained `then`, thus avoiding really nested code. Given the behavior above, you can simplify your code

```
var someResultPromise = Q.resolve().then(function () {
  var something = 'value';
  return callFunctionThatReturnsPromise(something)
}).then(function (result) {
  return processing(result);
});
```

Now I'm not sure why you'd start off with `resolve`. It's not necessary. You can simply just call that async operation. Simplifying even further:

```
var something = 'value';
var someResultPromise = callFunctionThatReturnsPromise(something).then(function (result) {
  return processing(result);
});
```

Comment: Joseph, `.then()` always follows the same rule - its callback passes on whatever is returned. Therefore the "do nothing" case will pass on `undefined`, not the original value. IIRC, early jQuery promises behaved as you describe but not since v1.8.3 .